# sharepoint WSS3can't export to spreadsheet field from type "Date and Time"

Tags: sharepoint, listview, list, export-to-excel

I have created a field in a list in Sharepoint WSS3.
The field's type is:"*Date and Time*" and the format is "*Date Only*".
When trying to **export to spreadsheet** a view that contains this field I get the following error :  **"can not the get the list schema column property from the sharepoint list".** 
Is there any way that I can export this data? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[give this a try](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/7f0cbeae-5cec-4fd2-a4a5-ba222e7d045a):

You can include the hotfix mentioned in the reference below to fix this issue.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941422

Alternatively, you can give a default value to the "Date and Time" column.

Comment: I've found the hotfix doesn't always make a difference, not sure why though